# Show .tiff/.tif image on chrome from its base64 encoded string with Javascript/Reactjs or convert it to any other (png/jpeg) format and display on UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, base64, buffer

I have a **base64** encoded string of a .tiff image that I get from the backend. If I decode it and then create a blob url, It works fine on Internet Explorer (by using on src of img tag).

I am not able to show it on Chrome. I have read some answers related to it where people are saying it is not supported on Chrome.

There are some libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff-to-png but they require an image to be stored somewhere and then use it to convert. I only have a base64 string of the image. I am not able to find any solution online. **My UI is built with ReactJs and backend is on Node**.

On backend, I have a buffer of the .tiff image which we are converting to base64 to send it to UI. If we can do anything on buffer, that is also possible. Please help.

Comment: "On backend, I have a buffer of the .tiff image which we are converting to base64 to send it to UI."  Why!!??  You're adding 33% overhead in bandwidth, not to mention extra CPU and memory, for zero benefit in almost all cases.

Comment: You can decode that TIFF client-side and display it on a canvas with a package like this:  https://github.com/image-js/tiff

Comment: @Brad So, you mean can I directly send buffer to UI? I read somewhere that to avoid dataloss (or something related to security) it is good to send the b64. Please let me know more about this. If you have any links, please send to me.

Comment: The documentation doesn't look clear to me. Do we have any examples for this https://github.com/image-js/tiff? Also, Can it take b64 and convert it and how would I show in Reactjs.

Comment: Where did you read that?  The only time you need to use base64 is if you're sending binary data within text.  There are plenty of client-side APIs for handling binary data directly.

Comment: Ow okay. I read it on line plus instructions from seniors. I think I need to investigate more and get myself clear with these options.

Comment: I've never used that library, and yes, it's documentation is woefully inadequate.  :-)  But, it says that once you decode, the pixel data is returned for each page.  You can take that data and then load it into a canvas via `putImageData`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData  If you're loading 8-bit or other formats, you may need to create the RGB data yourself in your code.

Comment: Okay, Let me try this out. If it would work, I will leave an answer to help others. If you find anything else or an example, please feel free to answer or comment. Thanks for the help.